# Dataloading in PyTorch using custom dataset

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to use the KAIST dataset in PyTorch to train a model and generate weights. I am new to both python and PyTorch and I am struggling using dataloaders with such a dataset. The dataset comes with png image files but the annotations (labels and bounding boxes) are in a .vbb format which i am having trouble converting to a usable form (i.e. csv, text file, etc.). So I guess my first question is, how would I convert the annotations to a format that I can iterate the png file with their associate annotations. The second question is, how would I create the dataloader for this dataset in PyTorch.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Link to dataset - https://github.com/SoonminHwang/rgbt-ped-detection/tree/master/data

There is a method to convert the annotations provided in the link above but I have been unable to get it to produce the correct results. Perhaps there is a simpler method for conversion via python?

Comment: I have manage to convert the annotations into json format using the link below. I am still unsure as to how to create a dataloader for PyTorch. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Link - https://github.com/SoonminHwang/caltech-style-dataset-converter